# Gnome has a built in sharing feature to transfer files between computers with the feature enabled, it isnt as simple as it seems. How do you do this?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, gnome, webserver, file-sharing

I would like to transfer files between my two linux computers, linux-desktop and linux-notebook. I would like it to be as easy as drag and drop given that is what is presented in Gnome here
[where you are seemingly able to setup drag n drop sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iNYQ.jpg)

is this at all possible without getting overly convoluted in the setup?

Comment: I took a quick look at the sharing section in my Ubuntu machine with Gnome installed. I enabled it and then used the values to connect in and could not.  I have already installed Samba in this machine and connect that way and file sharing does work with Samba.

Comment: Samba through gnome-files? i’ll check it out, if you know of a tutorial or walkthrough that makes sense, feel free to drop it here. Thanks @John

Comment: I did not mean Samba via Gnome - just Samba enabled so I can map a drive into Ubuntu from another OS.    Here is the tutorial I used:   
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba

Answer (score 0):

Your computers have to be on the same local network.

On computer A, you enable file sharing in gnome preferences, open a file manager and put some file in the "Public" folder. On computer B, open a file manager  and then go to "Other locations". Something like `computerAusername's public files on computerAhostname` should be there. You can read/write in this folder (from computer B).